# How do I maintain multi tenant data base connections nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Let's say I have a service app.js. Whenever a new client connects to the service , we will check if a mongodb connection is already establish for this client or not.

If it is not available then we will fetch the server ip, dbname ,collection name from a configuration file, connect to the db,and reply to the user.

Note: we can add a new client and corresponding info to Client Info at any time. (dynamically)

Client Info ClientId: ServerIp : Database Name :Collection Name I have tried to store mongo object in array so I can reuse them object based on database name from user's session data. But I keep running into circular json error. How do I store multi tenant database connections?

```
async.eachSeries(conf.clientDbs.clientsList, function(clientDetails,callback){
    console.log(clientDetails);
   mongodb.MongoClient.connect(conf.clientDbs.connection+clientDetails.dbName, function (err, database) {
        if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
        }
        // Save database object from the callback for reuse.
        var tempdbobj = {};
        tempdbobj["obj"] = database
        allDbs[clientDetails.team_id] = tempdbobj;
        console.log("Database connection ready for "+clientDetails.team_id);
        allDbs[clientDetails.team_id].obj.collection('collection_name').find({"ref_id":"111"}, function(dberr, testDoc){
            if (dberr) {
                console.log(dberr);
                callback();
            }
            else {
                console.log(testDoc);
                callback();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can actually switch the "database" namespace at any time with MongoDB. So typically you would not create multiple connections for this type of thing. Also the driver supports connection pooling by default, so there is another reason you would not want multiple connections.If you actually had separate "instances" altogether, then you probably should be managing with separate front end services as well. Overall, probably a bit to broad for a reasonable answer here.

Comment: I agree with you, this solution will work if  is fixed , let's new user connected and corresponding to new user ,we don't have any connection so first we have to connect on new ip than for same company another user we can use namespace as you told